# Field validations to compare two date fields in Flask-WTForms

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I have two form fields: start_date and finish_date. Now I want to check if the finish_date more or equal start_date. How can I implement it?

```
class AddChallenge(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    start_date = DateField('Start Date',
                           validators=[DataRequired(),
                                       DateRange(min=date.today())],
                           format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today)
    finish_date = DateField('Finish Date',
                            validators=[DataRequired(),
                                        DateRange(min=date.today())],
                            format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today)
    submit = SubmitField("Create")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
class AddChallenge(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    start_date = DateField('Start Date',
                           validators=[DataRequired()],
                           format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today)
    finish_date = DateField('Finish Date',
                            validators=[DataRequired()
                                        ],
                            format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today)
    submit = SubmitField("Create")

    def validate_finish_date(self, filed):
        if filed.data <= self.start_date.data:
            raise ValidationError('Finish date must more or equal start date.')
```

You can use such naming rules to customize the validation rules. Such as this `validate_yourfiledname`.

Answer (score 1):

Just had the same issue and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52134216/flask-wtform-validation-on-multiple-fields/52139328) where the built-in `validate()` function is enhanced. It solved my issue and is basically the same as the accepted answer. For the sake of completeness, in your case:

```
class AddChallenge(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('Title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    start_date = DateField('Start Date',
                           validators=[DataRequired()],
                           format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today)
    finish_date = DateField('Finish Date',
                            validators=[DataRequired()
                                        ],
                            format='%Y-%m-%d', default=date.today)
    submit = SubmitField("Create")

    # Custom validation function (redefine built-in)
    def validate(self, **kwargs):
        # Standard validators
        rv = FlaskForm.validate(self)
        # Ensure all standard validators are met
        if rv:
            # Ensure end date >= start date
            if self.start_date.data > self.finish_date.data:
                self.finish_date.errors.append('Finish date must be set after the starting date.')
                return False

            return True

        return False
```